# Career login forms swapped when given a cookie

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs, user-experience

Accessing the [career login page](http://curl%20'https://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/login'%20-H%20'Cookie:%20o=something') **with** cookies (happens most of the time):

```
curl 'https://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/login' -H 'Cookie: o=something'
```

[image]

Accessing the [career login page](http://curl%20'https://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/login'%20-H%20'Cookie:%20o=something') **without** cookies.

```
curl 'https://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/login'
```

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is because `o` is the cookie we use to determine whether you previously used OpenID to login or not. When the cookie is present we assume that you probably want to use it again and show the OpenID options on the left.

Comment: Looking at the layout on the bottom screenshot, I actually still visually process the OpenIDs section first. It occupies the center and occupies most of the area. But that's me. Did you implement this feature along your own ux-feeling, or have you experimented with some group and it was better to have it that way?

Comment: When I see a login page mysteriously changing, I assume someone is trying to steal my credentials.  I doubt the marginal improvement (if any) is worth it.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl honestly, this was implemented way before my time so I'll need to go investigate whether there were A/B tests involved. For candidates we're moving completely to SO for job seeking and the employer login screen is undergoing a redesign to look more like SO anyway so I expect this ceases to be a problem in, say, 6-8 weeks...